# How to fix Error: Choose either to return a promise or call 'done'. Do not use both in your script. in Azure Function?

Tags: node.js, error-handling, azure-functions, try-catch

I am trying to handle errors in my code (I am using Azure functions), so in my try catch block I added the following

```
try{
 something...
 context.res = {
      body: {
          status: 200,
          message: "Success"
         }
     };
     context.done()
    } catch (e) {
        context.log.warn(e)
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: {
                message: e,
            }
        };
        context.done()
    }
```

Although this works perfectly as I want, in the terminal I also get the following error

`Error: Choose either to return a promise or call 'done'. Do not use both in your script.`

What should I replace `context.done()` with to remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> > Error: Choose either to return a promise or call 'done'. Do not use both in your script.
> ```

The error states that you're using call and return method both in your script, You can use one method out of it to meet your requirements.

I have used the below code and my Function gets triggered without any error, I have used async method in addition to my Function Trigger, Refer below:-

**My index.js:-**

```js
  module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    try {

    const name = (req.query.name || (req.body && req.body.name));
    const responseMessage = name
        ? "Hello, " + name + ". This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
        : "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

    context.res = {
        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: responseMessage
    };
        const result = await doSomethingAsync();

        // Return a successful response
        context.res = {
            status: 200,
            body: {
                message: "Success",
                result: result
            }
        };
    } catch (e) {
        // Handle the error
        context.log.warn(e);

        // Return an error response
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: {
                message: e.message
            }
        };
    }
};
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

Add your dosomethingAsync logic in the code above.

There's also a bug reported in this [**github issue**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-nodejs-worker/issues/49) on the same error code, If required you can add your comment there.